# Execute parallel tasks with shared information in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing

Let‘s say I‘m building a program that accepts client connections, puts every new client into a list, prints the list to the console and updates whenever a new client connects.

At the same time (so while accept() is blocking the program flow; a client connects with a socket), I want to handle user input. The user shall always be able to choose a specific client from the list to communicate with by typing a number to the console (let’s assume that each client corresponds to a unique number (id)).

How can I achieve this in C? Should I use processes and exchange information by using shared memory or sockets or should I prefer threads? And why?

Although the title of my question is a little vague, this question is not a duplicate as I am asking for a method to use for this specific example.

Comment: You could use multiple threads, or you can use `select()` or `epoll()` to wait for data on multiple file descriptors.

Comment: Multiple processes instead of threads makes sharing information more complicated, but it also makes it easier to avoid stepping on the other process's toes.

Comment: This kind of question is a bit broad for [so]. We need you to ask specific questions about code you've written and are trying to get to work, not general design questions.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly do you mean by „stepping on the other process‘s toes“? §§  Is it too broad? Where should I put this question then?

Comment: I mean when you're processing one client you might update a variable related to a different client, because everything is in the same address space.

Comment: I don't know a good place for this type of question. You need to read tutorials on multi-threading and using select/epoll, then decide which would be easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I achieve this in C? Should I use processes and exchange information by using shared memory or sockets or should I prefer threads? And why?

Prefer threads because they are easier to work with.  Use mutex for data shared between threads, use pthread or winthread depending on your OS.  This will get you a working prototype as fast as possible.

Anything besides a working prototype can't really be assessed with the information you have provided.  How many clients, what OS, is the client list in RAM or on a disk (probably depends on client size), etc...?  Most things have trade-offs.

Comment: OS: Unix, clients: up to 100, probably way less (an average of 3-7); yup, clients are stored in RAM.

Comment: ok cool, so the prototype idea should work fine for your application since its already small scale.  Two pthreads for the user input and client connection tasks, getClientInfo/setClientInfo (or enque/deque or push/pop w/e you wanna do) which lock a mutex before accessing the shared data, then unlock before returning.  There should be plenty of examples out there on how to do this, should you decide to use this approach.  Follow the examples and you should have something functional in no time.